# Why are my private variables getting set to null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, state

I have an asp.net page. In the code behind I set a few private variables in order to temporarily store some values. The variables are initially set by user selection from a listview. The variables are getting assigned the correct values. however, by the time the click event for a button is fired the variables are set to null.

what's going on and how do I fix it ?

Comment: @Dman - With a few days in the ASP.NET trenches you won't need any sample code to understand this question.

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't been asked before, but a search of [asp.net][state] doesn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code-behind classes don't magically remember variable values. Your page is effectively stateless -- either you have to recreate the state on each post-back or persist the values you want in Session or ViewData or in a database.

There is [further information on how to implement state in ASP.NET here](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/ViewState)

Comment: Ahhh - Got me at the start too - the stateless nature of ASP.NET

Answer (score 5):

You can't store state in private member variables.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx for places you can store state information.